# Does ITIN require you to file taxes?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, non-resident, itin

For someone who is not a US resident, citizen or tax resident

If he has ITIN, is he required to file US taxes?

Answer (score 2):

Whether you have an ITIN or not does not affect which of your income is taxable in the US, and does not affect whether you are required to file US tax returns or pay US taxes.

Like any other nonresident alien, he would normally only be taxed by the US on US-sourced income, and he would normally only need to file a US tax return if he has US-sourced income.

However, he generally has to be filing a US tax return in order to get an ITIN in the first place. There are some other tax treaty reasons to get an ITIN without filing a tax return, but they are pretty rare.

Comment: Thanks. Side question. I learned that to maintain the ITIN, he needs to file taxes within 3 years. Say he has non-resident accounts. While filing US taxes, does he need to declare capital gains, or dividends even if the financial institution automatically takes the tax from the account based on the withholding tax treaty? Note that he normally doesn't need to file US taxes because he's not a US tax resident. He is just doing it so the ITIN wouldn't expire

Comment: Why do you need it to not expire?

Comment: @xqwxeqwex: NRA reports dividends on 1040NR and also reports the withholding which normally equals the tax liability leaving $0 owed. Cap gains (except real property and some partnerships) are not subject to withholding and are US-taxed only if you are actually present half the year (not the same as the 7701(b) "green card or substantial presence" test for other kinds of income); if that is the case, yes you report them and compute and pay the resulting tax.

Comment: NRA normally doesn't have to file 1040NR if he filled out a W8, right? You're talking about reporting dividends because OP wants to file taxes to keep the ITIN. In this case, you're saying he should report dividends, not capital gains (with exceptions)

Answer (score 1):

You've asked this question in several variations, and it appears that you want the ITIN as a US identifier even though you're not required to file anything with the IRS.

The IRS has a handy table [here](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1040nr#en_US_2022_publink100057473) that describes who **must** file the form 1040-NR. You can always file even if you don't have to, although I don't see why you'd do that.

The IRS will issue an ITIN if you need it for *tax* purposes. I.e.: if you *must* file a tax return, you can ask for an ITIN. I don't know if the IRS would issue an ITIN when you are not required to file. Strictly according to the regulations, they wouldn't. See [26 CFR 301.6109-1(d)(3)(ii)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/26/301.6109-1) and the [IRM 3.21.263.5.2](https://www.irs.gov/irm/part3/irm_03-021-263r#idm140619866118640):

> A new ITIN will NOT be issued unless the applicant proves they require the ITIN for federal tax filing, an allowable tax benefit, or tax reporting purpose

Generally, you are not allowed to use the ITIN for any purpose but tax. So using it as an identification number for credit reporting is technically not allowed. While it is not a crime, this use is not authorized by the IRS and is not a valid reason for issuing or renewing the ITIN. One must remember that ITINs expire and may be reused for someone else later, so they're not a permanent unique identifier in a way that SSNs are.

Comment: So you're saying you don't know. Okay, thanks for your input anyway. "So using it as an identification number for credit reporting is technically not allowed." if that's true, why do some banks accept ITIN instead of SSN for credit card applications?

Comment: You should ask them, but technically it's illegal. It most definitely isn't a valid reason for ITIN issuance.

Comment: @xqwxeqwex As to "I don't know" - all my research suggests that they wouldn't, they're only issuing ITIN to those who are **required** to file. But, as sometimes people make mistakes, you may be able to fall through the cracks.

Comment: Thanks. Can you link something that says it is illegal?

Comment: @xqwxeqwex I did, it's in the CFR definition.

Comment: https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/26/301.6109-1#d_3 This one? I couldn't find any information about legality of using ITIN for non-tax purposes in that link. As far as I know, millions of people use their ITIN to open dozens of millions of US credit card accounts. You're saying those people are committing some kind of crime? This makes no sense to me.

Comment: @xqwxeqwex doing something contrary to regulation is not necessarily a crime (although there's probably some catch-all provision in the criminal law to capture this under fraud or something). While the law demands ITINs to be used only for tax purposes, there's no specific punishment for using it for other purposes. However, the IRS may revoke it, expire it, cancel it, and make it otherwise unavailable to you as a mean of enforcement, which is if I understand correctly exactly what is happening to you.

Comment: "While the law demands ITINs to be used only for tax purposes" where I can find a source for that?

Comment: @xqwxeqwex CFR is a legal authority. It is the law. We're going in circles. I'll leave this as is, do what you want.

Comment: "While the law demands ITINs to be used only for tax purposes" Which law? Show me the law please? Tell me the keyword I should look up in that webpage to find the relevant part of the law? I think you're making things up because I'm not seeing literally anything in the law that supports your claim

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150617/discussion-between-littleadv-and-xqwxeqwex).

Comment: Well?..........

Comment: Well what? I explained everything to you,  you decided to disagree. Why are you still harassing me?

Comment: You did nothing other than wasting my time by writing random accusations

Comment: I answered your question, with sources and citations. You're welcome.